# Null list after query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem where I create an object containing a list, load it into my database, run a query that returns the object, but find the list null. All other properties of the object are as they should be. I'm using a list called "Ints" that is filled with a few integers but I've tried using other types.

Here's my model:

```cs
public class CourseModel
{
    public int CourseModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<int> Ints { get; set; } // the variable in question
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my database population (The database is called LearnYou):

```cs
public class LearnYouDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<LearnYouDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(LearnYouDbContext context)
    {
        context.Courses.Add(new CourseModel()
        {
            Name = "C# Programming",
            Overview = "You'll learn some C#",
            Ints = new List<int> { 1, 42, 3 },
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }        
}
```

Here's the controller code for querying the object:

```cs
// GET: Course/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        CourseModel courseModel = db.Courses.Find(id);

        // DEBUGGING THE PREVIOUS LINE SHOWS INTS IS NULL

        if (courseModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(courseModel);
    }
```

The "Ints" property is not null after saving the context in the database population part but is always null when it's queried (I visit the page ~Edit/1 to debug). I just can't figure out why when all other properties are fine. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming this is EF, you can't just have a collection of integers, you need an entity. Check your database - I doubt these are saved, which explains why they're not loaded either.

Comment: Are you using Code First configuration? If so, can you please share your configuration. An `ICollection` in a model should mean you have two tables, since it indicates a parent->child relationship. However, I doubt EF knows how to create a child table for an `int`.

Comment: I am using code first EF. So I have to create a class that inherits from some particular EF class for it to be stored as expected?

Comment: I think I've made a huge mistake. So I'm meant to have a configuration file that specifies which tables etc. to create in the database? What is this file called?

Comment: @PhloxMidas See my answer below. Your problem here is that you can't have a relationship for a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

An `ICollection` in a model indicates a Parent->Child relationship. However, I doubt EF will be able to determine how to create a child table for an `ICollection` of integers. Here is what I would do.

Create a new model Ints (or whatever it actually represents):

```
public class Ints {
    public int Value { get; set;}
}
```

Modify your original model to use it:

```
public class CourseModel
{
    public int CourseModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ints> Ints { get; set; } // See the difference?
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
}
```

That should make it work.

Comment: I tried changing the line to: Ints = new List<Ints>() { new Ints() { Value = 1 } } and got a ModelValidationException error. I think it might be a more fundamental configuration problem or something that I have failed to mention.

Comment: I think it's not gonna work. Because Ints have not foreign reference to courses

Comment: @PhloxMidas He is using Code First though and I know that 2 way references are not required in Code First. Can you post your Code First configuration in your question please. I bet you are missing the association part.

Comment: I'm really new at MVC so I apologize for the stupid question, but which file is the configuration file? web.config?

Comment: @PhloxMidas You said you are using Code First configuration. Which means you must have a class that extends from `EntityTypeConfiguration` to specify the configuration. Yes?

Comment: Yep. I'm an idiot. I thought code first meant something else (I thought there was slightly more magic happening under the hood). I have no such EntityTypeConfiguration class. I'll implement all of this stuff and give it another try. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

It Is not working because you are mapping directly to a int primitive type of .net and Entity Framework doesn't allow it.

In this case what you can do is create your onw object for example and sql table like

```
public class Ints {
{
      public Course Course { get; set; }
      public int IntValue { ger; set ; }
}
```

And referencing it from CourseModel

```
public virtual List<Ints> Ints { get; set; }
```